# How to use a lambda to specify a constructor argument?

Tags: c#, lambda, ninject

I am not overly familiar with implementing lambdas and expressions, but I've used to this syntax many times in MVC where the lambda is identifying a property on an object:

```
Html.Label(model => model.Foo)
```

In my app I am using Ninject conditional bindings to supply the instance of the `Settings` class which is injected when I request an instance of `Class`.  My `Class` looks like this:

```
public class Class
{
    private readonly Settings settings;

    public Settings Settings { get { return settings; } }

    public Class(Settings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }
}
```

I have some code which looks like this to get an instance of `Class`.  I am aware this is the [service locator anti pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), but we have no choice in this case due to other constraints:

```
var settings = new Settings();
var instance = Ioc.Instance.Get<Class>("settings", settings);
```

I would like to refactor it to look like this so that it is strongly typed, using a lambda to specify which argument on the constructor I am supplying:

```
var settings = new Settings();
var instance = Ioc.Instance.Get<Class>(x => x.settings, settings);
```

So, is this possible, and what would the code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually there is a lack of the factory (factory interface), so it should be introduced to avoid using the container directly.

The Ninject Factory (factory interface) extension could be used to create the instance, as follows:

Declare a factory interface:

```
public interface IFactory
{
    Class Create(Settings settings);
}
```

Add a binding to the composition root:

```
kernel.Bind<IFactory>().ToFactory();
```

Use the factory to get an instance:

```
var settings = new Settings();
var factory = Ioc.Instance.Get<IFactory>();
var instance = factory.Create(settings);
```

Please see the [ninject/ninject.extensions.factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki) for the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with constructor argument names and expressions is, that an expression is only valid / complete when it covers all parameters of the constructor. Now i suppose you want to inject a few of the parameters (have ninject handle them) and for one or two specific parameters you want to pass a value, let's say it looks like:

```
public interface IFoo { }
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo(IServiceOne one, IServiceTwo two, string parameter) {...}
}
```

Ninject supports ctor expressions, but only for bindings, and they work like this:

```
IBindingRoot.Bind<IFoo>().ToConstructor(x => 
    new Foo(x.Inject<IServiceOne>(), x.Inject<IServiceTwo>(), "staticArgument");
```

so instead of only specifying the "staticArgument" which you are interested in, you also have to specify `IServiceOne` and `IServiceTwo`. What if the constructor changes? Well the call needs to be adapted as well! Lot of work for just passing a single simple parameter.

Now if you still want to do this i'd suggest having a look at the `ToConstructor` code and creating a similar extension for a `Get` call which will translate some call

```
IResolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>(x => 
    new Foo(
         x.Ignore<IServiceOne>(),
         x.Ignore<IServiceTwo>(), 
         x.UseValue("mystring"));
```

to

```
IResolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>(new ConstructorArgument("parameter", "mystring"));
```

However, i would suggest going with @Sergey Brunov 's answer and use [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki). Now I think your going to say that it's no good because you'll still have to specify the parameter name,.. which is not refactor safe and a hassle (no code completion...).

However, there's a solution to the problem: Instead of using a constructor argument which "matches" the name of the argument, you can use a type matching argument.
Ok, there's a catch. If you've got multiple arguments of the same type,.. well it won't work. But i think that's seldomly the case and you can still introduce a container data-class to address it:

```
public class FooArguments
{
     string Argument1 { get; set; }
     string Argument2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now how can you use type matching?
There's two ways:

1. Use a `Func<string, IFoo>` factory. Just inject `Func<string, IFoo>` into where you want to create and `IFoo`.
2. Extend the Factory extension. Yes you've heard right ;-) It's actually not that difficult. You "just" need to implement a custom `IInstanceProvider` (also see http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/31/ninject-extensions-factory-introduction/) so you can something like:

```
public interface IFooFactory
{
    IFoo Create([MatchByType]string someParam, string matchByName);
}
```

(==> use an attribute to tell the factory extension how to pass the parameter to the `Get<IFoo>`request).

Comment: Thanks again for a very comprehensive answer.  I went with the Ninject factory option.  Even though it will break if the `setting` arg is renamed, at least the magic strings are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Look at following article -
http://handcraftsman.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/how-to-get-c-property-names-without-magic-strings/

Specifically

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<T,TReturn>(this Expression<Func<T,TReturn>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return body.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Note - This method may not work for all possible ways in which one can use expressions to indicate a property name for a class, and hence may need to be enhanced based on your needs (how generic you need it to be).

But essentially, once you have this helper method, your call becomes

```
var settings = new Settings();
Ioc.Instance.Get<Class>(GetPropertyName(x => x.settings), settings);
```

Comment: Does this work the constructor?  In my test I can only see properties on the class?